# Specifying a timeout with mapWithState in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am following a [sample of `mapWithState` function on Databricks website](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html).

The codes for trackstatefunction is as follow:

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[Int], state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
  val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
  val output = (key, sum)
  state.update(sum)
  Some(output)
}
```

I had a question in the case when state is timing-out `(state.isTimingout()==true)` then the function again update the sate which may cause an exception. Is this true for the sample?

Answer (score 4):

> In the case when state is timing-out (`state.isTimingout() == true`) then the function again update the sate which may cause an exception.

Yes, that is correct. If you set an explicit timeout on `mapWithState` and call `state.update` while the state is in the last timing out iteration that would cause an exception to be thrown as you cannot update the state once a timeout has occurred. This is explicitly stated [in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.State):

> State cannot be updated if it has been already removed (that is,
>   remove() has already been called) **or it is going to be removed due to
>   timeout (that is, `isTimingOut()` is true).**

---

In your example, an additional check is in order:

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                   key: String, 
                   value: Option[Int], 
                   state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
  val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
  val output = (key, sum)
  if (!state.isTimingOut) state.update(sum)
  Some(output)
}
```

Or, since `value` should only be `None` once a timeout occurs, you can use pattern matching as well:

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                   key: String, 
                   value: Option[Int], 
                   state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
  value match {
    case Some(v) => 
      val sum = v.toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
      state.update(sum)
      Some((key, sum))
    case _ if state.isTimingOut() => (key, state.getOption.getOrElse(0L))
  }
}
```

For a review of stateful streaming, see [this blog post](http://asyncified.io/2016/07/31/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-apache-spark) (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: hi @Yuval, so if a particular key time-outs, all the state is gone? you need to start from scratch?

Comment: @marios Yes, after the timeout elapses the key is marked for deletion.

Comment: I guess if you need to persist your state after a timeout you would need to do it yourself? Thanks Yuval!